# variable inside of function how to use that variable outside of function in python

Tags: python, function, variables, methods

How to use variable outside of function which is define inside of function?
And Function should declare in class.

```
class A:
  def aFunction(self):
    aVariable = "Hello"
```

Now here I want to use that `aVariable`

Comment: ```ob=A()```, ```print(ob.aFunction())```?? Add ```return aVariable``` inside the function

Comment: have you tried that @Sujay?

Comment: Yes? I did try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely more options that maybe others will provide, but these are the options I have come up with.

Use `return`

```
class A: 
    def aFunction(self): 
        aVariable = "Hello"
        return aVariable
obj = A()
var = obj.aFunction()
print(var)
```

use `global`

```
class A: 
    def aFunction(self): 
        global aVariable
        aVariable = "Hello"
obj = A()
obj.aFunction()
print(aVariable)
```

You can use `self` to your advantage

```
class A: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.aVariable = None
    def aFunction(self): 
        self.aVariable = "Hello"
obj = A()
obj.aFunction()
print(obj.aVariable)
```

Comment: Glad to hear. Please consider accepting the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: How to consider accepting answer? I'm new in stack overflow... Just today i join

Comment: Under the vote count of my answer. You should see a check mark. Click that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this variable within the class A, how about using an instance variable?

```
class A: 
    def aFunction(self): 
        self.aVariable = "Hello"
```

Now you can use self.aVariable in another function of the same class

Answer (score 1):

To use a variable from a class outside of the function or entire class:

```
class A:

    def aFunction(self):
        self.aVariable = 1

    def anotherFunction(self):
        self.aVariable += 1

a = A()  # create instance of the class
a.aFunction()  # run the method aFunction to create the variable
print(a.aVariable)  # print the variable
a.anotherFunction()  # change the variable with anotherFunction
print(a.aVariable)  # print the new value
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods you can try.

```py
class A:
    def aFunction(self):
        self.aVariable = "Hello"
    # you can access self.aVariable in the class
```

```py
class A:
    def aFunction(self):
        aVariable = "Hello"
        return aVariable
    # use self.aFunction() whenever you need this variable
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return` keyword will return the value provided. Here, you have provided `self.aVariable`. Then, you can assign the value to a variable outside the class and print the variable.

```
class A:

    def aFunction(self):
        self.aVariable = "Hello"
        return self.aVariable

a = A() #==== Instantiate the class
f=a.aFunction() #==== Call the function. 
print(f)
```

This will print: `Hello`

Comment: Thanks For your Help

Comment: Welcome @RaviCoder. Please accept the answer if it solves your issue